# php clearstatcache() performance and parameters explanation

Tags: php, stat, filemtime

i'm using `filemtime` for fingerprinting external resources in html, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen-<?=md5(filemtime('screen.css'));?>.css">
```

I noticed a significant delay between the effective updating and the timestamp returned by `filemtime`, so i added `clearstatcache()` at the top, which seems to solve the issue. But according to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php):

> you only need to call clearstatcache() if you are performing multiple
>   operations on the same filename and require the information about that
>   particular file to not be cached.

So i'm wondering if i'm using it correctly.

Also, i'm concerned about the performance of fully clearing the cache on every call. Can anyone tell me if it can cause a significant slowdown in the server?

---

`clearstatcache` also accepts two additional parameters, but i'm unsure of their meaning:

> **clear_realpath_cache** Whether to clear the realpath cache or not.
>
> **filename** Clear the realpath and the stat cache for a specific filename
>   only; only used if clear_realpath_cache is TRUE.

I don't get what "realpath cache" means, and i couldn't find any information about it. Does it make any sense to call `clearstatcache` this way:

```
clearstatcache(true,'/path/to/screen.css');
```

with the intent to clear only information related to that specific file (and therefore reduce the "impact" of `clearstatcache`)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `md5(filemtime('screen.css'))` instead of just `filemtime('screen.css')` -- A 128-bit hash of a 32-bit number is still only as good as the underlying 32-bit number.

Comment: @jedwards Just for the coolness of having digits AND letters ;-) but you're right, performance-wise

Comment: you could always do something like `dechex(filemtime('screen.css'))` or even `str_pad(dechex(filemtime('screen.css')), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` -- just an idea

Comment: @jedwards dechex seems to output really similar strings: 50b149a2, 50b152ba, 50b51803 ... while "the Firefox disk cache hash functions can generate collisions for URLs that differ only slightly, namely only on 8-character boundaries" ( from [Google best-practices](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching) ) ... so i need a longer, varied string

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  Interesting link too -- thanks.

Comment: Giona, the Google link has no reference to that now. I wonder if that Firefox bug resolved itself a long time ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using the function correctly.  Unless you're using other stat functions (as listed in the doc) that you *would* prefer cached, I don't know of a reason it would cause a significant slowdown.

When you `include('somefile')`, `somefile` could be in a number of different locations, as determined by things like your `include_path`, cwd, etc.  The realpath cache just eliminates the need to repeatedly search these locations.

For your use, your code seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Uhm, then should i use a "general" `clearstatcache()` or `clearstatcache(true,anyfileneeded)` ?

Comment: Most likely, I would use the general `clearstatcache()` function.  The only exception would be if I were doing many more stat functions that I *did* want cached.

Answer (score 2):

$clear_realpath_cache relates to calls to the [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function, the results of which are also cached.
This should have no impact on your calls to filemtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea why is the filename parameter "only used if clear_realpath_cache is TRUE", but it "clears the realpath **AND** the stat cache for a specific filename only"...?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give answer directly.

But I suggest you use `md5_file('screen.css')` instead of `md5(filemtime('screen.css'))`.

Comment: I don't know about this.  The two snippets do very different things.  The second takes a hash of a 32-bit integer.  The first takes a the hash of an entire file.  The first is almost necessarily more work.  (Although I don't see why `filemtime('screen.css')` isn't sufficient)